# How to create PostgreSQL user who can do everything **except** truncate et delete?

Tags: postgresql

My question is quite simple : after a recent database incident, I need to create a user that can do pretty much everything (not so much with regards to changing the schema, but that would be nice) **except** `TRUNCATE` and `DELETE`. I tried using commands like

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO user_name;
```

But then I can't import a CSV file in pgAdmin3 for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the error message you get when you import the CSV file? And how exactly do you "import" it?

Comment: You should also consider that UPDATE can be just as destructive as DELETE.     Changing all your customer names to "Bob" is going to cause nearly as much problem as deleting the customers would

Comment: @Gary Thanks Gary that is true but for my particular use case I am the only one who has access to the DB and I never do updates. I did however do a `truncate` thinking that I was in the dev environment...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the errors that I get (sorry it's in French) are `ERREUR: droit refusé pour la relation api_complementtitre` and then `no COPY in progress` and finally `COPY failed` when using the Import UI in pgAdmin.

Comment: `INSERT` is totally enough to `COPY` to table. Try copying with `psql` - maybe you have pgAdmin problem...